# how can I know that the data has been saved in my Android mobile app?

Tags: android, sql, database, android-layout, android-activity

i want to save the nbBeer, nbWhisky , nbWine, nbVodka, dateView in my database and how i can know the data has been saved?

```
nbBeer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nbBeer);
nbWhisky = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nbWhisky);
nbWine = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nbWine);
nbVodka = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nbVodka);

    //myDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.myDatePicker);

    dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateView);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    showDate(year, month+1, day);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);

     private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new         DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // arg1 = year
        // arg2 = month
        // arg3 = day
        showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
    }
};

private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    dateView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
            .append(month).append("/").append(year));
}
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

to add a product to the database:

```
 public void saveButtonClicked(View view){
Products product = new Products(nbBeer.getInputType(),     dateView.getText().toString(), nbWhisky.getInputType(),nbWine.getInputType(),            nbVodka.getInputType());
    dbHandler.addProduct(product);
}
```

and inside my DBHandler class I put:

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = " CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
            COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT" +
            COLUMN_BEERS + "INTEGER" +
            COLUMN_WHISKY + "INTEGER" +
            COLUMN_WINE + "INTEGER" +
            COLUMN_vodka + "INTEGER" +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    onCreate(db);

}
```

to add a new row the database:

```
 public void addProduct(Products product){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE, product.get_date());
        values.put(COLUMN_BEERS, product.get_beers());
        values.put(COLUMN_WHISKY, product.get_whisky());
        values.put(COLUMN_WINE, product.get_wine());
        values.put(COLUMN_vodka, product.get_vodka());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
```

and inside Products class

```
public class Products {
private int _id ;
private String _date;
private int _beers;
private int _whisky;
private int _wine;
private int _vodka;

public Products(){}
public Products(int beers, String date, int whisky, int wine, int vodka) {
    this._beers = beers;
    this._date = date;
    this._whisky = whisky;
    this._wine = wine;
    this._vodka = vodka;
}


public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public String get_date() {
    return _date;
}

public int get_beers() {
    return _beers;
}

public int get_whisky() {
    return _whisky;
}

public int get_wine() {
    return _wine;
}

public int get_vodka() {
    return _vodka;
}
}
```

Comment: As of **now**, it won't save **any data**, Because your table creation is completely wrong. As well as the table deletion. Fix those issues before attempting to insert any data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void addProduct(Products product){
try{
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_DATE, product.get_date());
            values.put(COLUMN_BEERS, product.get_beers());
            values.put(COLUMN_WHISKY, product.get_whisky());
            values.put(COLUMN_WINE, product.get_wine());
            values.put(COLUMN_vodka, product.get_vodka());
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
            db.close();
//To know that data add
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Everything OK =)",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: `db.insert()` returns the number of inserted rows. Simply check if it is **greater than 0**.

Comment: nothing changed unfortunately! since i am new to android development  please can you tell me how i can create a more effective table and save the data?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ it is will help u. I studed by it

Comment: You probably didn't read my previous comment (the one under your question).